# rails request.subdomain for a IP address?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, subdomain

If my domain is `test123.domainname.com` then
subdomain will be `test123` (I'm using rails request.subdomain)

But what is subdomain if my url is something like

1. a IP address e.g. 192.168.142.199
2. and www.test123.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-subdomain) and then [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0883f9f508a4d6791428adff12eaf7b882bd2da1/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/url.rb#L28) that:

1. will return an empty array
2. will return www

Answer (score 2):

1. If your domain is `test123.domainname.com`, and your subdomain is `subdomain`, then the full domain name will be `subdomain.test123.domainname.com`
2. If your domain is `domainname.com`, and your subdomain is `test123` the full domain name will be `test123.domainname.com`
3. Two-level domain name can be treated as a subdomain with a zone, like `subdomain.zone`
4. IP address has not subdomains, it is just an IP address.